# jQuery - move correlated elements

Tags: jquery

On page load, I want to wrap the header span with `div` and move it into the front of related body div.
ie, move `hApplicant1 span` into the front of `tabApplicant1 div`, etc.

How do I write jQuery to accomplish this? thanks !

Given:

```
<div>
            <div id="header">
                <span id="hDummy"></span>
                <span id="hApplicant1">James Smith</span>
                <span id="hApplicant2">John Doe</span>
                <span id="hApplicant3"></span>
                <span id="hApplicant4"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <div id="tabApplicant1">...</div>
                <div id="tabApplicant2">...</div>
            </div>
</div>
<div>
            <div id="header2">
                <span id="h2Dummy"></span>
                <span id="h2Applicant1">Black Smith</span>
                <span id="h2Applicant2">Shoe Maker</span>
                <span id="h2Applicant3"></span>
                <span id="h2Applicant4"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="body2">
                <div id="tab2Applicant1">...</div>
                <div id="tab2Applicant2">...</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

the result should be like this:

```
<div>
            <div id="header">
                <span id="hDummy"></span>
                <span id="hApplicant3"></span>
                <span id="hApplicant4"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <div><span id="hApplicant1">James Smith</span></div>
                <div id="tabApplicant1">...</div>
                <div><span id="hApplicant2">John Doe</span><div>
                <div id="tabApplicant2">...</div>
            </div>
</div>
<div>
            <div id="header2">
                <span id="h2Dummy"></span>
                <span id="h2Applicant3"></span>
                <span id="h2Applicant4"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="body2">
                <div><span id="h2Applicant1">Black Smith</span></div>
                <div id="tab2Applicant1">...</div>
                <div><span id="h2Applicant2">Shoe Maker</span><div>
                <div id="tab2Applicant2">...</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $bodyDiv = $('#body');

$('#header span[id^=hApplicant]').each(function(){
    $bodyDiv.find('div[id=' + $(this).attr('id').replace('h', 'tab') + ']').before( $(this).wrap('<div />').parent() );
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hw2Gz/

This can be further simplified (and optimized), but it should get you started on the right track.

---

**EDIT:**

This can be repeated:

```
var $bodyDiv = $('#body'),
    $bodyDiv2 = $('#body2');

$('#header span[id^=hApplicant]').each(function(){
    $bodyDiv.find('div[id=' + $(this).attr('id').replace('h', 'tab') + ']').before( $(this).wrap('<div />').parent() );
});

$('#header2 span[id^=h2Applicant]').each(function(){
    $bodyDiv2.find('div[id=' + $(this).attr('id').replace('h', 'tab') + ']').before( $(this).wrap('<div />').parent() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hw2Gz/1/

Comment: Guess we had the same idea. Just wondering, what's the .parent() for at the end of yours?

Comment: @Joseph: I have modified my question, it has two repeated container divs now. can you help to solve the puzzle? thanks!

Comment: @Richard D - Check your generated code. The `span[id^=hApplicant]`'s are not wrapped in `div`s. That's because they're left behind in the `#header`.

Comment: @Dean - You can simply repeat the same thing, again. See my updated answer. If this is really going to grow bigger and bigger, you should consider using classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#header span').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var thatId = that.attr('id');
        var bodyDiv = $('#body #' + thatId.replace('h', 'tab'));
        if (bodyDiv.length)
            that.insertBefore(bodyDiv).wrap('<div/>');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJtZc/3/